# Large Test Suite Using `fit` and Hit Jasmine Timeout

Tags: typescript, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have a pretty large test suite, over 250 tests, with more to add. I am running into an issue with `fit` when I use `fit` it gets to the end of the test, marks it passed, and then "runs through" skipping the rest of the tests and takes a very long time to do so. This is causing an exception in `jasmine-cover` and the browser never closes and I don't get any test results.

I did try using `fdescribe` in addition to `fit` and it still takes a long time to "run through and skip" the other tests.

So a couple of questions:

1. What is going on in the background while it is "skipping tests" that is taking so long?
2. What can I do to get test results again while using `fit` with this test suite?

Comment: Have you tried to suggestions listed on the protractortest.org site? http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts#timeouts-from-jasmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following to my `beforeEach()`

`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 999999`

Still not sure what the heck is going on in the background that takes so much time.